# Minecraft problem

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So i’m trying to play minecraft with my boyfriend (pocket edition), and there’s times when we’re on either the phone or on a party on the xbox app. well he tells me when he’s online but on my phone it doesn’t say he’s online. it takes us forever to even get on a world together, what do i do? It’s rare for us to get on the world together. we both have tried a lot. reconnecting to our wifi, restarting the app, unadding him as a friend and adding him back, i tried inviting him and vise versa, i have even went as far as deleting the whole app to try to get on a world with him, what do i do? i’m out of ideas!:(

Answer (score 0):

So if your friend is playing on Xbox, he should check his setting to make sure he doesn't have "appear offline" on. Maybe that will solve your problem as it is not possible to send people invites when they are appearing offline and only they can invite you **sometimes**

Answer (score 0):

This happened many times when I played with my online friend. It used to say "Unknown client: outdated server!" He also told me he was using 1.11.4, and I was using 1.12.0. So make sure you 2 are on the same version. If you don't mind, you can play in the Mineplex server and chat /party and then send /party invite [gamertag].